# Adding Postman Variables in JSON Post Body inside key name fields

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-collection-runner

So i have been making my postman collections as dynamic as possible, replacing all static content that only changes slightly during different API calls into variables, to decrease workload by quite a lot.

I have one thing left that i just cannot get to work, and that is building parts of the JSON body with Variables.

Here is the outcome i want, key values on the right works just fine:

```
{
  "act.getEntries": {
    "act.authToken": "{{authToken}}",
    "act.resourceId": "{{activelistid}}"
  }
}
```

I want to make the prefix dynamic for all my json arrays, like so:

```
{
  "{{prefix}}.getEntries": {
    "{{prefix}}.authToken": "{{authToken}}",
    "{{prefix}}.resourceId": "{{activelistid}}"
  }
}
```

I cannot use JS function in the JSON body, so i am limited to only escaping (so using ""''+)

I tried doing something like this:

```
{
  "\"" + '{{prefix}}'.getEntries": {
    "act.authToken": "{{authToken}}",
    "act.resourceId": "{{activelistid}}"
  }
}
```

But in the end, that produced a request body like so:

```
"{

 "\"" + ""act." + ".getEntries": {

 "act.authToken": "CJvGphuWp4wXOgJq1T6Yr0e_5aU1fvs2pXFDvJPBRnw.",

 "act.resourceId": "Hp2hTKmMBABDdFhotbrvBdw=="

 }

 }"
```

If anyone tried this before, please let me know, or else i will just mark it as not supported.

In pre-request and post-request tests i can use proper functions so it is easy, even the URL is created from variables, but the body seems impossible..

Outside of the Body, while still limited, i can easily insert variables into strings like so:

```
"reference": {
      "id": "",
      "isModifiable": true,
      "managerID": "iqzGK08BABCAXcbW2VGwrg==",
      "referenceName": "ActiveList",
      "referenceString": "<Resource URI=\"/All Active Lists/Personal/" + pm.variables.get("login") + "'s Active Lists/" + activeListName + "\" ID=\"\"/>",
      "referenceType": 24,
      "uri": "/All Active Lists/Personal/" + pm.variables.get("login") + "'s Active Lists/" + activeListName + "\""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I understand the question but I might be wrong. This seems to work fine for me:

```
{
  "{{something}}.getEntries": {
    "{{something}}.authToken": {{my_value}},
    "{{something}}.resourceId": {{my_value}}
  }
}
```

I have these save as `environment` variables as the values referenced in the POST body - These could be set in a pre-request script easily enough.

[image: Request Body]

When the request is sent, it sends through the variable values in the POST body:

[image: Request Body Sent]

I might be misunderstanding the question and what you're trying to achieve but i'm happy to update my answer if you provided more details.

Comment: I can't believe that worked after so much trying. It ended up being the IDE in postman that tricked me, as the color did not indicate it would be picked up as an actual variable :)
Thanks for pointing this out to me!